# Is it possible to perform some operations on the & selector inside a LESS mixin?

Tags: less

I'm trying to perform some string operations on the current selector `&` while inside a LESS mixin, but no matter what I try, I'm getting the `&` substitution character instead of the actual selector query. Is there a way to get the actual selector somehow or does the queue of operations in LESS prohibit doing that?

```
.mixin() {
  @current: &;
  test: ~`console.log("@{current}"), "@{current}"`;
}

.thing {
  display: block;
  .mixin();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I am repeatedly posting a similar answer/comment to your questions. But **no**, you can't do any operations on `&` (parent selector). It is just that - parent selector.

Comment: Don't be sorry, I'm glad to get experienced replies :) It's unfortunate though, I had hopes of porting my latest project into LESS, but it seems impossible without extending the language in some other way. Perhaps it could work as a plugin, but that implies way more time investment than I can commit to, not mentioning the increased complexity of implementation.

Comment: You could probably use a variable and send it as a mixin param but other than that I don't see any way to manipulate the parent selector (or) use it for substitution in any place other than a selector.  For example if you want `.class1.class2` as selector then you could do `&.class2` but if you want a property's value to be of the format `1px solid &` then you can't.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to directly modify the current selector, not just prepend or append something to it, but work with parts of the full query, not in the scope of a property value (that may have been confusing in the example, I was just trying to output it in console). Maybe if I just link the project, it might make the question clearer. Here goes: https://github.com/salsita/inStyle